# Valores duplicados no php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no banco que se chama brinquedo, dentro dela tenho as colunas nome, total, quantidade disponível e quantidade doado. Porem quero mostrar somente o nome, o total e a quantidade total doado.

Quando eu uso o código abaixo que eu sei que não é o que eu tenho que usar, me traz tudo porem eu tenho nome de brinquedo repetido nessa tabela, e eu queria que ela aparecesse uma só vez, e que o total viesse com o maior valor e a quantidade doada daquele brinquedo já somado.

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['rlanual']))
    {
        $ano1= $_REQUEST['rlanual'];

        $res = $mysqli->query("select * from brinquedo where ano=$ano1");
        $row1= $res->num_rows;  
         while($escrever = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $nome1 = $escrever['nome'];
            $total = $escrever['total'];
            $qtd = $escrever['qtd_disponivel'];
            echo "$nome1";
            echo "$total";
            echo "$qtd";


        }


    }
```

Para pegar o valor maior do total eu tenho isso:

```
$sql1=$mysqli->query('SELECT MAX(total) FROM brinquedo');
                             $result1 = $sql1;
```

Resumindo eu não quero que apareça o mesmo brinquedo mais de uma vez. Já tentei até comparação de string e nada.

Comment: Tente usar o GROUP BY pelo o nome do brinquedo direto no sua consulta.

Comment: eu tentei usar o selec count com o group by mas n foi. sempre fala q n pode converter em string ou em int e eu n sei mais o q fazer. desse jeito ai me traz tudo mas como tem nomes repetidos dai nao da pq e a parte de relatorio anual.

Comment: eu criei a tabela direto no banco e to usando paginas me php pra adicionar valores.

Comment: mas a tabela tem as seguinte colunas: ID, NOME, TOTAL, QTD_DISPONIVEL, QTD_DOADO.

Comment: Total está na mesma tabela, quando vc recebe um brinquedo novo vc atualiza o total de todos? acredito que total não precise estar na tabela, uma vez que pode ser feita uma soma diretamente pela query sql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar a seguinte query:

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM brinquedo WHERE ano = ' . $ano1 . ' GROUP BY nome');
```

Recomendo criar um índice na coluna *nome* para melhorar o desempenho da consulta.

Comment: tem uma coluna de id... porem como é relatorio eu tenho que pegar o ano que eu quero e listar tudo q ta la so q sem repetir o nome do brinquedo.

Comment: Leonardo, bem vindo! Podes explicar melhor a resposta? Assim fica mais completa e útil para quem tiver o mesmo problema e quiser compreender as respostas.

Comment: sou eu que estou com o problema. eu so quero que na hora de mostrar os registro em vez de mostra duas vezes o mesmo so mostre uma.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo o cenário

```
tabela - brinquedos

colunas
  id 
  nome
  quantidade_doada
  quantidade_disponivel
```

e que os dados internos sejam

```
id    nome        quantidade_doada    quantidade_disponível
1     bola        10                  9
2     bola        6                   6
3     carrinho    8                   8
4     blocos      80                  76
5     bola        6                   6
```

podemos gerar a resposta para um relatório de totalização da seguinte forma

```
SELECT nome, sum(`quantidade_disponivel`),sum(`quantidade_doada`) from brinquedos group by nome
```

isso vai gerar o seguinte resultado

```
nome      sum(`quantidade_disponivel`)  sum(`quantidade_doada`)   
blocos    76                            80
bola      21                            22
carrinho  8                             8
```

com isso basta usar o código php que já possui e imprimir as variáveis corretas.

Comment: h3nr1ke vou testar aqui e depois digo se funcionou. se o calor deixar eu testo hoje ainda heheh... thanks

Comment: deu certo!!! thanks
     
  if(isset($_REQUEST['rlanual']))
  {
   $ano1= $_REQUEST['rlanual'];

   $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT ano,nome, max(`total`) as t1,sum(`qtd_doado`) as t2 from brinquedo WHERE ano = $ano1 group by nome");
     $row1= $res->num_rows;
     while($escrever = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
   {
    $total = $escrever['t1'];
       $qtd_doado = $escrever['t2'];
    echo "     <tr>
     <td width='303' align='center'>".$escrever['nome']."</td>
     <td width='303' align='center'>$total</td>
     <td width='304' align='center'>$qtd_doado</td>
     </tr>
     ";}}echo "</table>";

Comment: aproveitando queria saber se consigo usar o where em mais de um lugar por exemplo dar um select ou um update onde o mes é nulo e o ano é igual ao ano.

$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT  *FROM `gusj_relatorio`.`vestuario` WHERE mes_fn is NULL, ano=$ano');

Comment: basta incluir o where no select `SELECT nome, sum(`quantidade_disponivel`),sum(`quantidade_doada`) from brinquedos group by nome where fieldFoo = 0 AND fieldBar = 1` ae vc ajusta o valores que quer testar e os campos.

Comment: muito obrigada!!!